# Session start and read pdf problems

Tags: php

I'm trying to open a pdf with help of php and something very strange is happening. With the following code below, the pdf does not open in Internet Explorer 8:

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
@readfile("*****");
```

Now if you remove the `session_start`, this now opens the PDF in the browser. And I really need to start the session obtain the path step `@readfile`. Someone can help me? It already did several tests and research without any result.

Comment: Look in the source code of the downloaded file to see what happens.

Comment: It appears that: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
`

Comment: The session_start() is a command on the server side and has no direct effect to the client. did you try to add the attachment header (content type is not enought) `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');`

Comment: @Uzumaki that's weird, that shouldn't be in there. Can you see where it comes from?

Comment: Check if session is enabled, that could explain why the script is working well when you don't have `session_start`

Comment: @ user1073122 No, if I do not I get any `session_start` value of session. If I do this command line you said, and the system will not let me download the file

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you all anyway

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem is to place after the `session_start ()` it:

```
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: public");
```

Thanks for all helps